# ngrx: awaiting of confirm or cancel in a custom dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

***ngrx, angular 7***

I need to delete item from list but before I should display a dialog for confirmation. I think best aproach for me is to show dialog via *side-effect*. I need to show up when delete action was dispatched, catch it in side-effect open a dialog component and return some kind of promise (confirm or cancel). I'm a little bit confused to do this, so I need your help, dear Stackoverflow.

**list.component.ts**

```
export class ListComponent {

    list: List;

    constructor(store: Store<fromStore.State>) { }

    deleteItem(itemId: string) {
        this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.DeleteItem);
    }
}
```

**confirm-dialog.component.ts**

```
export class ConfirmDialogComponent {

    constructor() { }

    confirm() {
        // return something to confirm deleting
    }

    cancel() {
        // return something to cancel deleting
    }
}
```

**list.actions.ts**

```
export enum ListActionTypes {
    DeleteItem = '[List] Delete Item',
    DeleteItemSuccess = '[List] Delete Item Success',
    DeleteItemFailure = '[List] Delete Item Failure',

    SetDialogVisibility = '[List] Set Dialog Visibility'
}

export class DeleteItem implements Action {
    readonly type = ListActionTypes.DeleteItem;

    constructor(public payload: string) { } // item id
}

export class DeleteItemSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = ListActionTypes.DeleteItemSuccess;

    constructor(public payload: string) { }
}

export class DeleteItemFailure implements Action {
    readonly type = ListActionTypes.DeleteItemFailure;
}

export class SetDialogVisibility implements Action {
    readonly type = ListActionTypes.SetDialogVisibility;

    constructor(public payload: boolean) { } // depends on this value I show or hide dialog
}

export type VoyagePageActions = CreateVoyage
    | DeleteItem
    | DeleteItemSuccess
    | DeleteItemFailure
    | SetDialogVisibility;
```

**list.effects.ts**

```
    export class ListEffects {

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private store: Store<fromStore.State>
    ) { }

    @Effect() DeleteItem$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(ListActionTypes.DeleteItem),
            map((action: DeleteItem) => action.payload),
            // show dialog
            // wait for answer
            // send http request to delete item
            // delete item from store
        );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the dialog doesn't have anything to do with state management.
Not everything has to get handled by an effect.

In the case of using angular material I would use the dialog service directly in your `ListComponent` to display the dialog, and then wait for either the confirm or cancel.

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(RemoveProjectDialogComponent, {
      data: project
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(async result => {
      // if result is set, it means the user clicked confirm
      if (result) {
        await this.projectService.remove(this.project.id);
        this.snackBar.open('Project removed');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    });
```

Comment: yes, it hasn't any access to store and I think it shouldn't becase this component is shared and it should be as simple as it could be. So I think it should connect with service or emit via `EventEmitter` confirm or cancel actions on the top level to the parent. And no, unfortunatelly this approach doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do that is by creating a `deleteItemConfirm` and `deleteItemCancel` actions. Instead of dispatching the `deleteItem` like initially, I dispatch the `deleteItemConfirm` and open a confirmation dialog and listen to the answer:

```
deleteItemConfirm$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ItemsListActions.deleteItemConfirm),
    map((action) => confirm('Are you sure?')
       ? ItemsListActions.deleteItem({id: action.id})
       : ItemsListActions.deleteItemCancel()),
));
```

You can easily replace the confirm dialog above with a Material Dialog and subscribe to it.